# stdin().read_to_string() drops terminal color: How do I avoid this?

Tags: rust, pipe, command-line-interface, stdin

I'm trying to create a program that has to accept piped terminal input, transform it and print it again.

I can't output the color, and it looks like it is actually lost on entry, as shown with this minimal reproducible example:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", load_stdin().unwrap());
}

fn load_stdin() -> std::io::Result<String> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let mut stdin = std::io::stdin();

    stdin.read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;

    Ok(buffer)
}
```

If you're on zsh, folders should be output in cyan, however if you run the above with `ls | cargo run` it will differ from `ls` in that regard.

How to avoid losing color information when reading from the terminal?

Can Rust keep that information into a `String` or do I need to read to a raw `&[u8]` and operate on those instead?
Will `println` preserve the color when printing to terminal, or do I need to use a lower-level alternative?

---

Edit: Actually, even reading directly to bytes and writing them all fails to preserve the color information. I though the issue was going from ANSI to UTF-8 encoding? Repro:

```rust
fn main() {
    stdout()
        .write_all(load_stdin().unwrap().as_slice())
        .unwrap();
}

fn load_stdin() -> std::io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    let mut stdin = std::io::stdin();

    stdin.read_to_end(&mut buffer)?;

    Ok(buffer)
}
```

Comment: It is `ls` that stopped producing colored output once it realized that its output was not being printed to a terminal but piped into `cargo run`. Try `ls --color=always | cargo run`

Comment: You're absolutely correct!

Comment: `ls` only uses colours when it outputs to a terminal. Your program is not a terminal. You can either ask `ls` to output colours anyway (try `ls --color=always`) or make your program emulate a terminal (requires low-level fiddling with unixy stuff).

Comment: Yes it works, even using `String` instead of `[u8]`. SO prompted me above to delete the question. Not sure what's the etiquette here? Am I OK to delete?

Comment: @doplumi Did it really? That is odd, you are generally not advised to delete questions unless they are poorly received and cannot be improved. In this case, it has received an upvote, so it might serve as a nice signpost to future visitors.

Comment: Yes, somebody must have singled as already answered elsewhere.
Maybe it only happens because no answer has been posted yet. If you answer it, I'll accept, it should go away.

Comment: This has been marked as a duplicate, but this doesn't mean that you should delete the question.